# Build a web client integrated facebook chat?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook-chat

I'm using Google App Engine and I'm interested in creating a web site integrated facebook chat.

I read [Integrating with Facebook Chat](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat) and with what I read, I think their example code only works for desktop applications. I tried some applications integrated facebook chat such as pidgin, meebo... There is a web client named tokbox but I think their chat application build on flash.

Does somebody know how to implement facebook chat to a web client by python ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Google App Engine has a [XMPP feature](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/), it could probably be what you need.

Comment: It seems unlikely you could integrate chatting as a particular Facebook user with other Facebook users using App Engine's XMPP service, which is my reading of what the OP wants.

Comment: yeah, GAE's XMPP service can't connect to facebook chat. I think it only works for google talk.